# What of all the rest of the universe, in the MCU?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

As far as I'm aware, it seems all the action we've witnessed in the MCU takes place in our galaxy (right?) or at least among a small collection of locations.

Yet I'm pretty sure that the events in *Avengers: Infinity War*

> are meant to affect "half of life in the universe" (I think there's a quote to this effect).   And the Infinity Stones clearly are meant to be unique in the universe as they were forged by the Big Bang, yet they are all within reasonable proximity.

**So what of all the other billions of galaxies?**

Are they just happily chugging along and then

> POOF! to half their population?

Or do other populated galaxies not exist in the MCU?

Comment: We know that it is at least 2 galaxies, because Guardians is in the Andromeda galaxy, not the Milky Way.  Also not real clear with that V planet is, it could be in a third galaxy.

Comment: @DaveJohnson, Fair, but for the record, ["the number of galaxies in the observable universe range from 200 billion (2×10^11) to 2 trillion (2×10^12) or more"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galaxy)....   (Last I checked 3<<200,000,000.)

Comment: Sadly, the scene where we see a virtually infinite number of unnamed characters across the universe disappear was ultimately cut from the film. Apparently some editors didn't like the idea of a century-long third act.

Comment: Ooops, I meant 200,000,000,000.

Comment: There's a reasonable chance that the Captain Marvel movie will show us some life on other planets, and perhaps this will then be integrated into the great disappearance when we pick up with the next IW movie.

Comment: I'm sure half the universe disappearing across galaxies and all will appear in the sequel to the  infinity war movie

Comment: Most of the movies' space locations are set in the Solar system (Earth and Titan moon)

Comment: @aminabzz It is Titan the planet, located in a different system far away, not Titan the moon of Jupiter (I think it was). That's why Iron Man and Nebula get stranded on their way back *far away from any jump point or habitable planet*.

Answer (score 7):

According to the infinity gauntlet story line that was in the original comics, half of all life in the **universe** was destroyed at the snap of thanos’ fingers.

[image: thanos speaking with death about destroying half the life in the universe.]

[image: Thanos actually destroying half the life]

Answer (score 3):

Yes this happened all over the universe. Firstly, we know from *Avengers: Infinity War* that his motivations were to wipe out half the universe.

> **Thanos:** Little one, it's a simple calculus. This universe is finite, its resources finite. If life is left unchecked, life will cease to exist. It needs correction.
>
> **Gamora:** You don't know that!
>
> **Thanos:** I'm the only one who knows that. At least, I'm the only one with the will to act on it. For a time... you had that same will... as you fought by my side. Daughter.
>
> <sub>*Avengers: Infinity War*</sub>

Gamora previously confirmed this to Thor as well after they picked him up.

> **Gamora:** The entire time I knew Thanos, he only ever had one goal: To bring balance to the Universe by wiping out half of all life. He used to kill people planet by planet, massacre by massacre...
>
> <sub>*Avengers: Infinity War*</sub>

In *Avengers: Endgame* Carol conforms this by saying she’s helping people out universe wide after what Thanos did.

> **Carol Danvers:** Listen, fur-face, I’m covering a lot of territory out here. The things that have been happening on Earth have been happening everywhere else. On thousands of planets. You might not see me for a long time.
>
> <sub>*Avengers: Endgame*</sub>

Of course we also know other populated galaxies and planets exist in the MCU as the Guardians films take place in the Andromeda galaxy. And we also see various other populated planets and Realms across the Guardians and Thor films.

Comment: **BRUCE BANNER:** *You murdered trillions.*

Comment: @Valorum, he killed all life, I imagine there’s trillions of life just on Earth. The more explicit quotes are better in my opinion.

Comment: I think it's fairly likely that Banner is referring to people, not trees or woodlice

Comment: @Valorum Presumably but it doesn’t really add much to the answer.

Comment: IIRC, trillions applies to all life forms, not just the ones aware of their existence. So, ant colony populations must have been halves as well. Now I wonder if Thanos spared queen ants, otherwise it is just as good to destroy half the colonies rather than half the colony population.

Comment: Makes you wonder what Thano's QA department is like - certainly seems like some use cases he may not have factored into the minimum viable release of the snap